# Having Trouble with a test class getting Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [RecallApproval].<Constructor>(String) at line 34 column 37

Tags: apex, code-coverage

Help would be greatly appreciated.  My Class is this:

```
/**
 * Apex utility to allow for the Recall of Approval requests based on Process builder actions
 
 */

public class RecallApproval {

    @InvocableMethod(label='RecallApproval')

    public static void RecallApproval1(List<id> recId){

            ProcessInstanceWorkitem[] workItems = [ SELECT Id

                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem

                WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :recId ];

            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 

            pwr.setAction('Removed');

            pwr.setWorkItemId(workItems[0].id);

           

            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(pwr);

    }

}
```

I wrote a test class but am not able to get coverage because I don't think it's running the Class details.  And I think it's because I am not passing the ID of the new quote created in my test class.

But when I pass the quote.id it gives me the error in my test class:

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class RecallApproval1TestClass {

 static testMethod void RecallApproval() {

Test.startTest();
       Opportunity opp = new Opportunity( Name = 'Test', CloseDate = System.Today().addDays( 3 ) );
       opp.StageName = 'Closing';
       opp.OwnerId = '0051U000004niwIQAQ';
       insert opp;       


       quote quote = new quote( name = 'Test'  );
       quote.OwnerId = '0051U000004niwIQAQ';
       quote.opportunityid = opp.id;
       quote.status = 'Denied';
       quote.service_included__c = false;
       quote.Pricebook2Id = '01s1U00000AIiIeQAL';
       insert quote;
       
       QuoteLineItem QuoteLineItem = new QuoteLineItem ( Product2Id = '01t1U000004d5NeQAI');
       QuoteLineItem.Quantity= 1;
       QuoteLineItem.UnitPrice = 1.00;
       QuoteLineItem.pricebookentryid = '01u1U000003d78nQAA';
       QuoteLineItem.quoteid = quote.id;
       insert QuoteLineItem ; 
              
     String recId = quote.id;
        
            RecallApproval recall = new RecallApproval(recId);    
            
            
            ProcessInstanceWorkitem[] workItems = [ SELECT Id

                FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem

                WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :quote.id];


            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest pwr = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 

            pwr.setAction('Removed');

        
        
 Test.stopTest();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is static and has no constructor. You cannot, and do not need to, instantiate it like this:

```
        RecallApproval recall = new RecallApproval(recId);
```

You must call its static method, as declared, with a `List<Id>` parameter:

```
RecallApproval.RecallApproval1(new List<Id>{recId});
```

Additionally, your test class should not hard-code any Salesforce Ids, but should always generate all of the data it requires inside test context or source through `Schema` or `Test` methods, for things like the standard Pricebook Id and Record Type Ids. You should write meaningful assertions to validate the behavior of your code under test.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the help.  I don't write much Apex as you can tell and mostly try to leverage declarative methods.